# How to try catch ws error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm using nodejs using WebSocket "ws" to connect to another server B.

However, sometimes when the server B is not reachable, mainly "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" problem will stop my server, which is not accepted, I should use a try catch to handle the situation and try to connect later.

Where should I put the try catch? It won't trigger the ws.onerror callback.

I've found a similar situation in 
[How to catch getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662619/how-to-catch-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

but I've no idea how to use that approach to the ws interface.

Comment: Just attach an error event handler to your connection. `ws.on('error', function(){})`.

Answer (score 3):

Try as below:

you can use domain which never down your server A

```
 var domain = require('domain');

 var d = domain.create();

 d.on('error', function(er) {        
    setTimeout(function() { createConnection() }, 60000); //create connection after 1 minute
});

d.run(function() {
    createConnection()
});


var createConnection = function() {
    //Create Connection with server B
}
```