# Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when there is no internet connection

Tags: node.js, http, express

Normally, everything works, but when there is no internet connection my app throws an error:

```
    events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

    /* my code - putting this to try...catch have no effect: */
    var http = require('http');
    // (...)
    var req = http.request(options, response => {
       /* ... */
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
```

So what can I do when internet connection shuts down and I would like to prevent my app from stopping?

Comment: You need to show the rest of your server code and I'd also recommend giving more information about how the app is running, is it running via `node` or is it being run by a process manager like `pm2` or `forever`? Are you running it locally? Is being run at `localhost`? You don't need an internet connection or even an active network connection in order for the `http` module to create a server that is listening locally.

Comment: @peteb I am running it locally by node, but the domain which I am requesting to is on external server; i am not creating a server but only get data by code above and show response by console.log

Comment: If something is offline and not local, you can't request it. Thats just how it works.

Comment: @peteb but I want to prevent situation when my app is running on server, trying connect to external server but by unexplained reason there is no internet connection on my server-side (is this even possible?). When that case occurs my app will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent your `app` from stopping when external server's internet connection is down, you can catch `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error and return error message to your end client. Please check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662619/how-to-catch-getaddrinfo-enotfound) on how to catch `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error.

In your case, the code would be:

```
var http = require('http');
// (...)
var req = http.request(options, response => {
   /* ... */
});
req.on('error', function (err) {
    // Check error type and console.log corresponding message.
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```